Pandas: how do I vectorize this loop calculation?
I'm currently applying the for loop below to a pandas dataframe with fields prob, id, and time. How can I vectorize this?
Deterministic example input generated by the following code:
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(0)
probs = [i / 10 for i in range(11)]
ids = [i for i in range(5)]
rowcounts = [i for i in range(2, 6)]
times = [i for i in range(14)]

example = []
for idn in ids:
    rowcount = random.choice(rowcounts)
    pvals = sorted(random.sample(probs, rowcount))
    tvals = sorted(random.sample(times, rowcount))
    for i in range(rowcount):
        example.append([idn, pvals[i], tvals[i]])
df = pd.DataFrame(example, columns=['id', 'prob', 'time'])

Loop calculation follows. Expected output of vectorized expression is the same as applying this loop calculation to the example input above.
import numpy as np

data = []
for cutoff in np.sort(df['prob'].unique()):
    # get subset of records where prob >= cutoff
    sub = df[df['prob'] >= cutoff]
    # from that subset, for each ID get the record with minimum prob 
    subsub = sub.loc[sub.groupby('id')['prob'].idxmin()]
    # for those records, compute various statistics on the time field
    times = subsub['time'].values
    data.append([cutoff, np.quantile(times, 0.5), np.quantile(times, 0.9), (times <= 7).sum()/len(times)])
metrics = pd.DataFrame(data)


Please provide a [mre] (example input/expected output)

@mozway I second that. For specifics, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

sometimes code can't be vectorized because it has too complex calculations.

Check numpy.transpose and numpy.reshape
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#define data and make an array
matrix= {
'x': [1, 2, 3],
'y': [4, 5, 6],
'z': [10, 11, 12]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
arr= np.array(df)
#convert matrix to victor
shp = np.shape(arr)
vec = np.reshape(arr,(1,shp[0]*shp[1]))
print(vec[0])

Output:

[ 1  4 10  2  5 11  3  6 12]


Check "walrus operator := " to assign variables and make  more complex loop when using list comprehension

How does that address my question?

Check my last answer is that what you want?

Is this code helps or you mean you need algorithm without using for loop at all for this problem?
import numpy as np
data = [[times := df[df['prob'] >= cutoff].loc[df[df['prob'] >= cutoff].groupby('id')['prob'].idxmin()]['time'].values,[cutoff, np.quantile(times, 0.5), np.quantile(times, 0.9), (times <= 7).sum()/len(times)]] for cutoff in np.sort(df['prob'].unique()) ]
data=[i[1] for i in data]
metrics = pd.DataFrame(data)

or
import numpy as np
data = [[times := df[df['prob'] >= cutoff].loc[df[df['prob'] >= cutoff].groupby('id')['prob'].idxmin()]['time'].values,[cutoff, np.quantile(times, 0.5), np.quantile(times, 0.9), (times <= 7).sum()/len(times)]] for cutoff in np.sort(df['prob'].unique()) ]
data=np.delete(np.array(data,dtype="object"), 0, axis=1)
shp = np.shape(data)
data = np.reshape(data,(1,shp[0]*shp[1]))[0].tolist()
metrics = pd.DataFrame(data)

this code for same example you provide.
